# UK Life Expectancy (Either HLE or LE) by small area

Tags: data-request, uk

I have managed to track down the UK Life Expectancy statistics for multiple different criteria, but not by local area.

Ideally this would be by either Lower Super Output Area (LSOA) or by 2015 election ward.

The idea would to then be able to compare life expectancy across a city or county.

I have tried data.gov.uk and neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk as well as a few other sources (such as DataHub.io), but cannot find anything that provides this type of data in a usable format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.